# How to set jQuery UI dialog box positioning in relation to different buttons?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI dialog box, which is being triggered by clicking on different buttons on the page.
How can I set the dialog box positioning in relation to its own trigger?

Here is my code so far:

```
<script>
var dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
        modal: true,
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $('#btn-quote').css('z-index',1042);
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').on('click', function() {
                dialog.dialog('close');
            });
        },
        position: {
            my: "center top",
            at: "center top+50",
            of: $('#btn-quote')
        }
});
$("#btn-quote, #btn-quote-contact").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        dialog.dialog("open");
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `$(this)` to reference the trigger button.

```
<script>
var dialog = 
function openDialog(el){
    var dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 300,
            height: 400,
            modal: true,
            open: function(event, ui) {
                $('#btn-quote').css('z-index',1042);
                $('.ui-widget-overlay').on('click', function() {
                    dialog.dialog('close');
                });
            },
            position: {
                my: "center top",
                at: "center top+50",
                of: el
            }
    });
    dialog.dialog("open");
}
$("#btn-quote, #btn-quote-contact").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        openDialog($(this));
});
</script>
```